# how to get dynamic route prefix

Tags: laravel, routes, middleware

I'm trying to create a dynamic route prefix with middleware.

i have tried like this in my `web.php`:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => '{role}', 'middleware'=>'operator'], function() {
    Route::get('/whatever', function() {
        dd('halo');
    });
});
```

my operator middleware :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    dd(Route::current()->uri());
}
```

but when i hit `/Admin/whatever`, the output of dd is like this `"{role}/whatever"`. it should be like `Admin/whatever` that right ?

so the idea is, when I login let's say as Admin, I want to redirect like this `/Admin/home`.

edit: 
also i tried this in operator middleware :

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    dd($role));
}
```

but give me error Too few arguments to function...

Comment: Please try this bro.
`Route::group(['prefix' => '{role}', 'middleware'=>'operator'], function() {
    Route::get('/whatever', function($role) {
        dd('halo');
    });
});`
i'm not tested it. but it should do.

Comment: do note the prefix expects that you are statically going to define it, not it getting it from the URL

Comment: tank you for the response, it still `{role}/whatever`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is data not available to middleware since it is spun up so early in the lifecycle. Session data isn't available, and it seems that the route is not fully formed before the middleware is ran. There is a different method that you can use that will return the parameters passed to the route though.

`\Route::getCurrentRoute()->parameters`
or `$request->route()->parameters`, whichever you prefer.

This will give you a list of all parameters as `{key} => value` pairs so

`\Route::getCurrentRoute()->parameters['role']` 
or `$request->route()->parameters['role']`

Should give you what you're looking for.

Comment: session data might be available, it depends on where you defined the middleware in `Http/Kernel.php`

Answer (score -1):

You can retrieve your parameter using:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::current()->role;
```

or better:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::current()->parameter('role');
```

If you dump the contents of `Route::current()` you'll see what object you're actually having:

`dump(Route::current());`

results in:

```
Route {#330 ▼
  +uri: "{role}/whatever"
  +methods: array:2 [▶]
  +action: array:5 [▶]
  +isFallback: false
  +controller: null
  +defaults: []
  +wheres: array:3 [▶]
  +parameters: array:1 [▶]
  +parameterNames: array:1 [▶]
  #originalParameters: array:1 [▶]
  +computedMiddleware: array:2 [▶]
  +compiled: CompiledRoute {#461 ▶}
  #router: Router {#26 ▶}
  #container: Application {#2 ▶}
}
```